# Vb.Net PictureBox Resize image in runtime

Tags: vb.net

appreciate your help.

So I have an image (293 X 117 px) being placed in a PictureBox inside a Form. The layouts of control is perfect in the From; however, when I run the application the form is displayed but it seems the image is resized!!
I have the the **SizeMode** set to **Normal**

Comment: Start from here: [How to configure an app to run correctly on a machine with a high DPI setting (e.g. 150%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi Woow the thread was posted 9 years ago:o) do you think it is still relevant?

Comment: Yes and no. It depends on what .Net version you're targeting. Since your app is clearly not DpiAware (from the images you have now removed), it appears you're targeting .Net Framework, not .Net 5+ (which handles this in a different way), it can be relevant. But also read here: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms) -- If you decide to target .Net 5+, prefer `PerMonitorV2` as DpiAwareness mode.

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for the valuable information and for pointing out the articles.

Answer (score 0):

This worked

Disabling DPI-awareness to fix HDPI / scaling issues with Windows Forms Designer in Visual Studio:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/disable-dpi-awareness?view=vs-2022

Comment: That's the really wrong choice (very wrong).

Comment: @Jimi. do you have a better way of doing this!  Please elaborate.